# array is not returning if has the same key or value

Tags: php

```
$arrays = array (
    'child1_167'=>'1st', 
    'child1_167'=>'2nd', 
    'child1_165'=>'2nd', 
    'child2_165'=>'1st', 
    'child3_164'=>'2nd', 
    'child1_164'=>'' 
);

$classes = array();
foreach ($arrays as $key=>$value) {

  if($value != '') {
      $exp= explode('_', $key);
      $classes[$exp[0]] = $exp[1];

  }

}
 print_r($classes);
```

currently it is returning like this:

```
Array ( [child1] => 165 [child2] => 165 [child3] => 164 )
```

but i want it to return all the keys and value if value is not blank.

I am actually getting the data from form.
and my actual code is foreach ($_post as $key=>$value )

```
<td>
  <select name="child1_<?php echo child_id(); ?>">
   <option></option>
   <option>1st</option>
   <option>2nd</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <select name="child2_<?php echo child_id(); ?>">
   <option></option>
   <option>1st</option>
   <option>2nd</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <select name="child3_<?php echo child_id(); ?>">
   <option></option>
   <option>1st</option>
   <option>2nd</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

and here is the form post data.

```
Array ( [child1_167] => 1st [child2_167] => 2nd [child3_167] => [child1_165] => [child2_165] => 1st [child3_165] => 2nd [child1_164] => 2nd [child2_164] => [child3_164] => 1st ) Array ( [167] => 2nd [165] => 2nd [164] => 1st )
```

Comment: You are using associative arrays, you **can't** have two entries with the same name.  Can you post what you are looking for the array to actually look like at the end?

Comment: Thanks for adding the way you are gettign your data, but can you give us an idea of what your data will look like while you are using it?  And for sake of convenience, go ahead and do a print_r($_post) to show what that looks like?

Comment: I am sorry for convenience,
form post data looks like this.


Array ( [child1_167] => 1st [child2_167] => 2nd [child3_167] => [child1_165] => [child2_165] => 1st [child3_165] => 2nd [child1_164] => 2nd [child2_164] => [child3_164] => 1st ) Array ( [167] => 2nd [165] => 2nd [164] => 1st )

Comment: What is that second array?

Are both of the arrays in your comment part of the post data?

Comment: Sorry it is the mistake. Only the first array contains the form data.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with the form data you gave here, and put in an example loop that keeps all the values. The important thing that it and the other commenters are saying, is that you will need to use the multi-dimensional arrays, because your key of 'child1' etc will have more than one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the array you provided in the comments her as an example that has all the values, storing them as a two-dimensional associative array:

```
 $arrays =  Array ( 
        'child1_167' => '1st' ,
        'child2_167' => '2nd' ,
        'child3_167' => '',
        'child1_165' => '',
        'child2_165' => '1st' ,
        'child3_165' => '2nd' ,
        'child1_164' => '2nd' ,
        'child2_164' => '',
        'child3_164' => '1st' ,
        ) ;


$classes = array();
foreach ($arrays as $key=>$value) {

  if($value != '') {

      $exp= explode('_', $key);
      $child_number=$exp[0];
      $child_id=$exp[1];
      $child_order=$value;
      $classes[$child_number][$child_order] = $exp[1];

  }

}
 print_r($classes);
```

And this is the output:

```
Array
(
    [child1] => Array
        (
            [1st] => 167
            [2nd] => 164
        )

    [child2] => Array
        (
            [2nd] => 167
            [1st] => 165
        )

    [child3] => Array
        (
            [2nd] => 165
            [1st] => 164
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that array keys must be unique, but you're setting the same key `child1` with three different values (`167`, `167` and `165`) so you're just overwriting the same entry each time.

What you could do is:

```
$classes = array();
foreach ($arrays as $key=>$value) {
  if($value != '') {
      $exp= explode('_', $key);
      $classes[$exp[0]][] = $exp[1];

  }
}
```

which will generate a multi-dimensional array

Comment: Looking a the original post, it definitely looks like a multidimensional array will be in the cards, using '1st', '2nd' etc to indicate the order they should be in the sub-arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrays = array (
    'child1_167'=>'1st', 
    'child1_167'=>'2nd', 
    'child1_165'=>'2nd', 
    'child2_165'=>'1st', 
    'child3_164'=>'2nd', 
    'child1_164'=>'' 
);
```

The key are uniques if you print $arrays on the begin you will find the answer:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrays);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Array
(
    [child1_167] => 2nd
    [child1_165] => 2nd
    [child2_165] => 1st
    [child3_164] => 2nd
    [child1_164] => 
)